Dell Latitude 9440 2in1 fingerprint reader
I have a Dell Latitude 9440 (13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1365U) with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Running lspci or  fwupdmgr get-devices gives no information about the fingerprint reader.
Is it possible to get the fingerprint reader working on it?
